# Optimized way to get "get_Item" MethodInfo

Tags: c#, reflection, items, methodinfo

Right now, I have: `targetType.GetMethod("get_Item", BindingFlags.Instance)`

Is there anything better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefer to use [`PropertyInfo.GetIndexParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getindexparameters.aspx):

```
var indexers = targetType.GetProperties(bindingFlags)
                         .Where(p => p.GetIndexParameters().Any());
                         .Select(p => p.GetGetMethod());
```

Now `indexers` is an `IEnumerable<MethodInfo>` of the getters of the indexers that match the specified `BindingFlags` given in `bindingFlags`.

Note how the code reads like from the `targetType`, get the properties that match the `bindingFlags`, take those that are an indexer, and then project to the getter. It is much less mysterious than using the magic string `"get_Item"`, and multiple indexers are handled easily.

If you know there is only one, you could of course use `Single`. If you are looking for a specific one of many, you can inspect the result of `GetIndexParameters` accordingly.

Comment: I want the MethodInfo, not the PropertyInfo.

Comment: @smartcaveman: Wow. `Use PropertyInfo.GetGetMethod` on what I have given you above.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way is to retrieve the DefaultItemAttribute for the class.  It has the name of the indexer property.  It doesn't have to be "Item", languages like VB.NET allows specifying any property to be the indexer.  Jason's code will also fail on them, there can be more than one indexed property.  But only one default.

Comment: Do you have any documentation for this?  I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: MSDN, look at the VB.NET Default keyword and the DefaultMemberAttribute class.